# How to copy an interface value in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, interface

How to copy an interface value in Go?

My `User` interface:

```
type User interface {
    Name() string
    SetName(name string)
}
```

My `Admin` struct:

```
type Admin struct {
    name string
}

func (a *Admin) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a *Admin) SetName(name string) {
    a.name = name
}
```

I try to copy `user1`'s value.

Main Function:

```
func main() {
    var user1 User
    user1 = &Admin{name:"user1"}

    fmt.Printf("User1's name: %s\n", user1.Name())

    var user2 User
    user2 = user1
    user2.SetName("user2")

    fmt.Printf("User2's name: %s\n", user2.Name()) // The name will be changed as "user2"
    fmt.Printf("User1's name: %s\n", user1.Name())  // The name will be changed as "user2" too, How to make the user1 name does not change？
}
```

How to achieve that changing the copy's name the original doesn't change?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem here is that your `user1` variable (which is of type `User`) holds a *pointer* to an `Admin` struct.

When you assign `user1` to another variable (of type `User`), the interface value which is a pair of the dynamic type and value `(value;type)` will be copied - so the pointer will be copied which will point to the same `Admin` struct. So you only have one `Admin` struct value, both `user1` and `user2` refer (point) to this. Changing it through any of the interface values changes the one and only value.

To make `user1` and `user2` distinct, you need 2 "underlying" `Admin` structs.

One way is to [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the value in the `user1` interface value, and make a copy of that struct, and wrap its address in another `User` value:

```
var user2 User
padmin := user1.(*Admin) // Obtain *Admin pointer
admin2 := *padmin        // Make a copy of the Admin struct
user2 = &admin2          // Wrap its address in another User
user2.SetName("user2")
```

Now they will be distinct, output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6qi1pxmdHz)):

```
User1's name: user1
User2's name: user2
User1's name: user1
```

Of course this solution has its limitation: the dynamic type stored in the `User` interface value is "wired" in the solution (`*Admin`).

#### Using reflection

If we want a "general" solution (not just one that works with `*Admin`), we can use reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package).

For simplicity let's assume `user1` always contains a pointer (for now).

Using reflection we can get the dynamic type (here `*Admin`), and even the dynamic type without a pointer (`Admin`). And we can use [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) to obtain a pointer to a new value of that type (whose type will be identical to the original dynamic type in `user1` - `*Admin`), and wrap this back into a `User`. This is how it could look like:

```
var user3 User
user3 = reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(user1).Elem().Type()).Interface().(User)
user3.SetName("user3")
```

Output (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pT8VE9md3b)):

```
User1's name: user1
User3's name: user3
User1's name: user1
```

Note that `reflect.New()` will create a new value which is initialized to its zero value (so it will not be a copy of the original). It's not a problem here as `Admin` only has one field which we're about to change anyway, but must be kept on our mind in general.

Our initial assumption was that `user1` contains a pointer. Now the "full" solution must not make such assumption. If the value in `user1` would not be a pointer, this is how it could be "cloned":

```
var user3 User
if reflect.TypeOf(user1).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    // Pointer:
    user3 = reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(user1).Elem().Type()).Interface().(User)
} else {
    // Not pointer:
    user3 = reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(user1)).Elem().Interface().(User)
}
user3.SetName("user3")
```

Comment: Additional, assume user1.Name is "USER ONE",
**user2 = reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(user1).Elem().Type()).Interface().(User)**
The user2.Name is empty string, how make it same as user1?

Answer (score 9):

Another solution could be to add a Clone() method to your User interface:

```
type User interface {
    Clone() User
    Name() string
    SetName(name string)
}

type Admin struct {
    name string
}

func (a *Admin) Clone() User {
    u := *a
    return &u
}

func (a *Admin) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a *Admin) SetName(name string) {
    a.name = name
}

func main() {
    var user1 User
    user1 = &Admin{name:"user1"}

    fmt.Printf("User1's name: %s\n", user1.Name())

    var user2 User
    user2 = user1.Clone()
    user2.SetName("user2")

    fmt.Printf("User2's name: %s\n", user2.Name())
    // output: User2's name: user2

    fmt.Printf("User1's name: %s\n", user1.Name())
    // output: User1's name: user1
}
```

Of course in this case, the implementation gets linked to the interface, which might not be desired, but that's a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more generic way to do that.

```golang
func Clone(oldObj interface{}) interface{} {
    newObj := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(oldObj).Elem())
    oldVal := reflect.ValueOf(oldObj).Elem()
    newVal := newObj.Elem()
    for i := 0; i < oldVal.NumField(); i++ {
        newValField := newVal.Field(i)
        if newValField.CanSet() {
            newValField.Set(oldVal.Field(i))
        }
    }

    return newObj.Interface()
}
```

However, it has one pitfall: it cannot set unexported fields. It can be worked around using [this](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/uLZ5qQtfz54) solution with the help of `unsafe`'s black magic, but I would rather avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is using a library (I'd recommend https://github.com/jinzhu/copier) combined with some reflection magic:

```
var cloneObj MyCustomStruct = reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(sourceObj).Elem().Type()).Interface()
copier.Copy(cloneObj, sourceObj)
```

This gives you a deep copy of the source struct correctly typed (which is important). If you don't use an interface, you may need to customize the reflection use a bit (remove the `.Interface()`).