# Reflect accessed map does not provide a modifiable value

Tags: dictionary, go, reflection, slice

### Context

In the process of writing a generic diff and patch algorithm I faced a problem with reflection in go.

When I'm trying to patch in a slice I have no problem, `reflect.ValueOf(&slice).Elem().Index(0).CanSet()` returns true. This allows me to patch anything inside the slice element, be it a slice of primitive or of structs.

### Problem

However when I attempt this with a map `reflect.ValueOf(&map).Elem().MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("key")).CanSet()` returns false. This prevents me from attempting to do anythnin with the content of my map.

#### Examples

**Slice**

```
s := []string{"a", "b", "c"}

v := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()

e := v.Index(1)

println(e.String())
println(e.CanSet())
e.Set(reflect.ValueOf("d"))

for _, v := range s {
    print(v, " ")
}

output :
b
true
a d c
```

**Map**

```
m := map[string]string{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"}

mv := reflect.ValueOf(&m).Elem()
println(mv.MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("a")).CanSet())

output:
false
```

How could I get a modifiable value out of a map through reflection?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a limitation of the `reflect` package. Slice index expressions are addressable (e.g. `&s[0]` is valid for example), so slice elements obtained via reflection will be settable. Map index expressions are **not** addressable (e.g. `&m["a"]` is invalid), so values of keys obtained via reflection will not be settable. See related [How to update map values in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716852/how-to-update-map-values-in-go/42716918#42716918)

Only addressable values are settable, attempting to "set" a non-addressable value could only modify a copy (and not the original value), so it's not allowed in the first place. Quoting from [`Value.CanSet()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet):

> CanSet reports whether the value of v can be changed. A Value can be changed only **if it is addressable** and was not obtained by the use of unexported struct fields.

If you want to change the value assigned to a key in a map using reflection, use the [`Value.SetMapIndex()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.SetMapIndex) method:

```
mv.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf("a"), reflect.ValueOf("11"))
fmt.Println(m)
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AFRDohn3Lb2)):

```
map[b:2 c:3 a:11]
```

Note: taking the address of a map index expression (and allowing to change a value using reflection) is not allowed because the internals of a map may change at any time (e.g. if new key-values are added to the map, the implementation may have to re-structure the way it stores the key-value pairs internally), so a possible pointer you would obtain by `&m["a"]` may not exist (or may point to another value) by the time you end up using it. To avoid such confusions and run-time panics, this is not allowed in the first place.

Comment: Go says Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices. So why is it so that we can not Set the value of Maps Since it is also a reference type

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunately I need to modify the content of the Value retrieved with MapIndex later in the code, this is why I need this Value settable. Is there a way to make a settable copy of a unsettable value?

Comment: @B.Delor No, there is not. As explained, a settable `reflect.Value` would prevent the runtime to operate the map normally, it could not change its internal structure, or the `reflect.Value` would become invalid / corrupt.

Comment: Thanks @icza for explanation. So slice index will not going to change like maps since they are not making a copy of their values when you are looping over it.

Comment: @Himanshu Elements in a slice are not moved around "arbitrarily" by the runtime, while map values may be.

Comment: This is why I was asking for a copy, it would be disconnected from the map, live on it's own and sporting a copy of the content of the map's accessed Value. Then I'll modify this copy and finally push it back in the map with SetMapIndex

Comment: Is there any go reference supporting this.

Comment: @B.Delor You can do that, but ultimately you have to call `Value.SetMapIndex()`.

Comment: I'm wondering how to do that, I might be googling wrong but I'm gaving a hard time finding how to copy the the content of an unsettable value to a new, settable value ^^

Comment: @B.Delor Read this answer: [How to copy an interface value in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851500/how-to-copy-an-interface-value-in-go/37851764#37851764) You may use `reflect.New()` to obtain a pointer to a newly allocated value of some type, wrapped in a `reflect.Value`, which will be settable.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your help