# Cloning a struct when only the interface is known

Tags: go, interface, clone

Interfaces in go consist of a reference to a struct - does this mean they cannot be copied / dereferenced properly? I have recreated [my problem](https://play.golang.org/p/8CeaMY4OogE) below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Animal interface {
    getName() string
}

type Dog struct {
    Name string
}
func (d Dog) getName() string {; return d.Name; }

func getTwo(a Animal) []Animal {
    b := a
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Name":"Bella"}`), a)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Name":"Buster"}`), b)

    return []Animal{a, b}
}

func main() {
    l := getTwo(&Dog{})

    fmt.Printf("dog 1 is called: %s\n", l[0].(*Dog).getName())
    fmt.Printf("dog 2 is called: %s\n", l[1].(*Dog).getName())
}
```

This currently outputs:

> dog 1 is called: Buster
>
> dog 2 is called: Buster

Is it possible to dereference `b` from `a` (preferably without reflection)?
I'm looking for an answer which only modifies the `main` or `getTwo` method (the rest of the methods are mocked). Obviously getTwo should be able to handle both Dogs and other Animals (like it currently does)

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851500/how-to-copy-an-interface-value-in-go ?

Comment: @EliBendersky - yes, thanks for finding that. I'll close this one as a dup